# How to center superfish menu

Tags: superfish

I have found this templatedemo: http://sunflower62.pas-solutions.ch/index.php?id=10

Givs a change to center the menuitems? I have found a few tutorials, but the menu is allways left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the text-center, display: inline-block trick and remove the floats.

```
.sf-menu {
    text-align: center;
}

.sf-menu li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

Of course, if you have sub-menu items you will need to position them correctly.

To fix the sub-menu you can use:

```
.sf-menu ul {
    text-align: center;
    display: block !important;
    max-width: 12.5rem;
}
.sf-menu ul li{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But now the menu is in 3 colums and the submenu don't work for me

Comment: I edited wit a solution for the sub-menu. Because you didn't even post any attempt of your own and I don't see it, I'm not posting a solution for it breaking into 3 columns.

Comment: Thank you. I have edit it, but it break into 2 or 3 colums. When i change it with your lines in the demo with firebug, it break

Comment: Sorry. At this moment I don't have a open Server to show you. When you go to Demo and change the lines for sf-menu and sf-menu li with Firebug you see the break into 2 colums

Comment: Thank you. I will try one more. It works when i don't insert the sf-menu ul li. I try one more time

Comment: You might just need to add media queries to make the items break at a larger breakpoint.